# How can I dynamically set a SortDirection for Neo4j Graphql in javascript?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, neo4j, graphql

I'm using neo4j's graphql library and it uses enums for SortDirections, like this:

```
enum SortDirection {
    ASC
    DESC
}
```

And I would like to be able to dynamically set this from my React Native application, but I'm not sure how I would go about it because I can't just reference `DESC` - the closest I have come up with is making it a string, which doesn't work `"DESC"`.

```
let options = { sort: { originalValue: sortDirection }, limit: 10 }
```

Since it's an enum and not a string, `"DESC"` doesn't work. But I'm not able to just write `DESC` because it's not a defined variable in my javascript application, any idea what to do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this was a silly mistake. The String `"DESC"` does seem to work!